# Rendering local files in Elm with FileReader

Tags: elm

I am using [simonh1000's file-reader](https://github.com/simonh1000/file-reader) to upload image files.  I would like elm to display the contents of a file when they are drag-n-dropped.

I should be able to render an `img` with blob data directly in the `src`, but I am not sure how to get FileReader.elm to output a `src` value acceptably.

```
[ div [ class "panel" ] <|
    [ p [] [ text "User Avatar" ]
    , div dzClass
        [ label
            [ class "custom-file-upload"]
            [ input
                [ Html.Attributes.type_ "file"
                , FileReader.onFileChange OnDrop
                , multiple False
                ]
                []
            ]
        ]
    , case model.file of
        Just nf ->
            div []
                [ span [] [ text nf.name ]
                , button [ onClick (StartUpload UserAvatar) ] [ text "Upload" ]
                , div [] [ small [] [] ]
                , img [src FileReader.parseSelectedFiles] [] -- This is what I want to do
                ]

        Nothing ->
            text ""
```

However, the compiler gives me this error:

```
The argument to function `src` is causing a mismatch.

488|                                 src FileReader.parseSelectedFiles
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Function `src` is expecting the argument to be:

    String

But it is:

    Json.Decode.Decoder (List NativeFile)

Detected errors in 1 module.
```

All of the methods in [FileReader.elm](https://github.com/simonh1000/file-reader/blob/master/src/FileReader.elm) seem to have return types that are incompatible with the `src` attribute.  Is there a practical way to convert this?

Comment: In short, you need to follow the familiar Elm Architecture approach, and use the OnDrop message to attach the native files to your model. From there they can be used in the view function. https://github.com/simonh1000/file-reader/blob/18f9536278a490457ca69399debae014096475bf/examples/Ex3-DD-DataUrl.elm might give you some ideas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're currently trying to handle all of this in your `view` function. The way the Elm Architecture works, you'll need to integrate the behaviors of your `view` and `update` functions. The pipeline you want is:

- Display a file selection dialog (in the `view`, you already do)
- User selects a file (causes an `OnDrop` message)
- Parse the file content into a data URL (invoke the `readAsDataUrl` command)
- Store the parsed data URL in the model, perhaps converted to a string using `Json.Decode.decodeValue`
- In your view function, if available, use the parsed data URL as the argument to `src`.

Your `update` will need to handle the two cases of an initial drop (`OnDrop`) and successful/unsuccessful parsing of the data inside:

```
update msg model =
   case msg of
      OnDrop (nf :: _) -> 
         model ! [Task.attempt DataURL (FileReader.readAsDataUrl nf.blob)]
      DataURL (Ok dataUrl) ->
         { model | parsedDataUrl = Json.Decode.decodeValue Jason.Decode.string dataUrl |> Result.withDefault "error.png" }
      ...
```

In your view, pass the model.parsedDataUrl in as the image's source.